# leaflet variable for import data geojson

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I just used a leaflet. From the geoJSON demo page I saw if you want to include data you have to use

```
<script src="data/us-states.geojson"></script>
```

and if you open the files looks like

```
var ustates = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
......
[]
};
```

and if you want to call them use

```
var data = [ustates] ;
```

Is there another way to call the data? The geojson file that I have has no initial variable and looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
......
[]
}
```

I have lots of data and I have to open 1 by 1 to add variable on geojson data so I mean can I just call the data like

```
var ustates = <?php include "data/us-states.geojson"; ?>
var data = [ustates];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use follow this [link](https://github.com/WeAreFairphone/fprsmap/blob/482b20cc127f978f31db4eac753a1de4842e2676/js/main.js#L5)

```
function fetchJSON(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}


var data = fetchJSON('data/us-states.geojson');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy plugin which will help with this - leaflet-ajax - which you can find here https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax. This will handle fetching the file and creating a Leaflet layer from it in one easy step.

Example usage:

```
var geojsonlayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/us-states.json").addTo(map);
```